# Macros en Word se borran de una PC a otra

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

He creado una macro en un documento word guardado como .docm los macros no los incrusto en botones si no directamente en el Ribbon, es decir creo una nueva pestaña y dentro de este agrego grupos y aqui incrusto las macros en mi PC tod funciona bien el problema es que este documento se le envio a otra persona en mi trabajo via email, usb o red las macros y las Ribbons se borran del Documento.

Entonces no se como solucionar el problema para que las macros y pestaña y grupos creados no se borren al pasar a otro PC.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es un complemento, asi la otra persona en otro pc solo tendria que agregar el complemento, la forma mas sencilla de crear tu complemento seria guardando tu archivo word con las macros con formato "Plantilla habilitada con macros de word", ahora para que tu personalizacion de la ribbon si las hiciste con xml no tendras problemas pero si la creaste desde las opciones de excel pues en ese caso tendrias que exportar tu personalizacion en xml, podria orientar por telegram @MichaelTorrez, yo hago mis complentos pero para excel no hay mucha diferencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu macro no se borra si entras al VBA ahi está la macro, lo que se debe realizar en cada pc es programar nada mas los botones, pero si lo que quieres es ejecutar la macro solo dale "Alt + f11" y asi ejecutas la macro, otra solucion posible es llamar esa macro de word desde excel haciendolo con el metodo "call" y listo se ejecuta tu macro.